# Select records based on Id and most updated record of the same Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `Applications`

The user can submit more than one application. The user can also update an existing application, but instead of updating the record itself, we will insert a new record with the same `ApplicationNumber`

```
Id  ApplicationNum    ApplicantId     ApplicantName  CreateDate

1    101              789              John          May-20-2021
2    101              789              John          May-21-2021
3    102              789              John          May-22-2021
4    103              123              Maria         May-31-2021
```

I want to return the list of applications based on the `ApplicantId`, but I don’t want to display both records of the same `ApplicationNumber`

If I use this select statement

```
Select * from Applications where ApplicantId = 789
```

This is the result I currently get

```
1    101              789              John          May-20-2021
2    101              789              John          May-21-2021
3    102              789              John          May-22-2021
```

This is the result I **want** to get

```
2    101              789              John          May-21-2021
3    102              789              John          May-22-2021
```

Notice that record `Id = 1` is not displayed because it is an old version of record `Id = 2`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

I like using `ROW_NUMBER` along with a `TIES` trick here:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM Applications
WHERE ApplicantId = 789
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicantId, ApplicationNum ORDER BY Id DESC);
```

Comment: I know you like it, but it's inefficient compared to `WHERE rn = 1` as it requires a sort

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to just use:

select max(Id) as Id, ApplicationNum, ApplicantId, ApplicantName, max(CreateDate) as CreateDate

from Applications

where ApplicantId = 789

group by ApplicationNum, ApplicantId, ApplicantName

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way which is *usually* the most performant is to use `row_number` and select the desired row from each group of Applicants

```
select Id, ApplicationNum, ApplicantId, ApplicantName, CreateDate
from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by ApplicantId, ApplicationNum order by Id desc) rn
    from Applications
    where ApplicantId=789
)a
where rn=1
```